# How to specify breaks for y axis in R plot

Tags: r, plot

I have created the following fanchart using the `fanplot` package. I'm trying to add axis ticks and labels to the y axis, however it's only giving me the decimals and not the full number. Looking for a solution to display the full number (e.g 4.59 and 4.61) on the y axis

I am also unsure of how to specify the breaks and number of decimal points for the labels on the y-axis using `plot()`. I know doing all of this in `ggplot2` it would look something like this `scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(min(data.ts$Index),max(data.ts$Index),by=0.02))` . Any ideas on how to specify the breaks in the y axis as well as the number of decimal points using the base `plot()` feature in R?

Here is a reproductible of my dataset `data.ts`

```
structure(c(4.6049904235401, 4.60711076016453, 4.60980084146652, 
4.61025389170935, 4.60544515681515, 4.60889021700954, 4.60983993107244, 
4.61091608826696, 4.61138799159174, 4.61294431148318, 4.61167545843765, 
4.61208284263432, 4.61421991328081, 4.61530485425155, 4.61471465043043, 
4.6155992084451, 4.61195799200607, 4.61178486640435, 4.61037927954796, 
4.60744590947049, 4.59979957741728, 4.59948551500254, 4.60078678080182, 
4.60556092645471, 4.60934962087565, 4.60981147563749, 4.61060477704678, 
4.61158365084251, 4.60963435263623, 4.61018215733317, 4.61209710959768, 
4.61231368335184, 4.61071363571141, 4.61019496497916, 4.60948652606191, 
4.61068813487859, 4.6084092003352, 4.60972706132393, 4.60866915174087, 
4.61192565195909, 4.60878767339377, 4.61341471281265, 4.61015272152397, 
4.6093479714315, 4.60750965935653, 4.60768790690338, 4.60676463096309, 
4.60746490411374, 4.60885670935448, 4.60686846708382, 4.60688947889575, 
4.60867708110485, 4.60448791268212, 4.60387348166032, 4.60569806689426, 
4.6069320880709, 4.6087143894128, 4.61059688801283, 4.61065399116698, 
4.61071421014339), .Tsp = c(2004, 2018.75, 4), class = "ts")
```

and here is a reproductible of the code I'm using

```
# # Install and Load Packages

## pacman::p_load(forecast,fanplot,tidyverse,tsbox,lubridate,readxl)

# Create an ARIMA Model using the auto.arima function


model <- auto.arima(data.ts)


# Simulate forecasts for 4 quarters (1 year) ahead

forecasts <- simulate(model, n=4)

# Create a data frame with the parameters needed for the uncertainty forecast


table <- ts_df(forecasts) %>% 
  rename(mode=value) %>% 
  mutate(time0 = rep(2019,4)) %>% 
  mutate(uncertainty = sd(mode)) %>% 
  mutate(skew = rep(0,4))

y0 <- 2019
k <- nrow(table)

# Set Percentiles 

p <- seq(0.05, 0.95, 0.05)
p <- c(0.01, p, 0.99)

# Simulate a qsplitnorm distribution

fsval <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(p), ncol = k)
for (i in 1:k) 
  fsval[, i] <- qsplitnorm(p, mode = table$mode[i], 
                           sd = table$uncertainty[i],
                           skew = table$skew[i])

# Create Plot

plot(data.ts, type = "l", col = "#75002B", lwd = 4, 
     xlim = c(y0 - 2,y0 + 0.75), ylim = range(fsval, data.ts), 
     xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", ylab = "",xlab='',
     main = '')

title(ylab = 'Log AFSI',main = 'Four-Quarter Ahead Forecast Fan - AFSI',
      xlab = 'Date')

rect(y0 - 0.25, par("usr")[3] - 1, y0 + 2, par("usr")[4] + 1, 
     border = "gray90", col = "gray90")


fan(data = fsval, data.type = "values", probs = p, 
    start = y0, frequency = 4, 
    anchor = data.ts[time(data.ts) == y0 - .25], 
    fan.col = colorRampPalette(c("#75002B", "pink")),  
    ln = NULL, rlab = NULL)


# Add axis labels and ticks

axis(1, at = y0-2:y0 + 2, tcl = 0.5)
axis(1, at = seq(y0-2, y0 + 2, 0.25), labels = FALSE, tcl = 0.25)
abline(v = y0 - 0.25, lty = 1)
abline(v = y0 + 0.75, lty = 2)
axis(2, at = range(fsval, data.ts), las = 2, tcl = 0.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`range(blah)` will only return two values (the minimum and maximum). The `at` parameter of `axis()` requires a sequence of points at which you require axis labels. Hence, these are the only two *y* values you have on your plot. Take a look at using `pretty(blah)` or `seq(min(blah), max(blah), length.out = 10)`.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions of @Feakster are worth looking at, but the problem here is that the y-axis margin isn't wide enough.  You could do either of two things.  You could round the labels so they fit within the margins, for example you could replace this

```
axis(2, at = range(fsval, data.ts), las = 2, tcl = 0.5)
```

with this

```
axis(2, at = range(fsval, data.ts), 
labels = sprintf("%.3f", range(fsval, data.ts)), las = 2, tcl = 0.5)
```

Or, alternatively you could increase the y-axis margin before you make the plot by specifying:

```
par(mar=c(5,5,4,2)+.1)
plot(data.ts, type = "l", col = "#75002B", lwd = 4, 
     xlim = c(y0 - 2,y0 + 0.75), ylim = range(fsval, data.ts), 
     xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", ylab = "",xlab='',
     main = '')
```

Then everything below that should work.  The `mar` element of `par` sets the number of lines printed in the margin of each axis.  The default is `c(5,4,4,2)`.

Comment: Thanks @Dave Armstrong! I combined your ```sprint``` solution and @Feakster 's ```seq()``` solution to get an axes with breaks as well as rounded numbers